# Issues with moving a Unity3D 5 project to another computer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to move my project to another computer by creating a package in assets -> export package and then transfer the package. But when I create a new Unity project in the the other computer and import the package I don't have my prefabs and can't open my scene(s). But when I create a new project in the current computer where I started my main project and import the package it works fine.
What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure both are running Unity 5?

Comment: Just copy your project folder (or compress it in a ZIP first), paste the folder on the other computer, and tell Unity to open the project folder with the Open Other button.

Comment: @Chris When you say project folder - du you mean "Project setting" folder?

Comment: @LocDaiLe No, that's only the project settings. You want to copy the parent folder of that. So if your project is called "MyProject", copy the "MyProject" folder that contains the Assets, Library, ProjectSettings folders.

Comment: You can (and probably should) ignore the Library folder. Packages are about distributing resources to other projects